# change bundle identifier but keep preferences

Tags: cocoa, macos

I have a Mac OS X Cocoa app. I want to be able to change its bundle identifier for a future release, but retain the preferences (bundle identifier in ~/Library/Preferences). I'm blanking on how to copy those over on launch into a preference file with the new identifier. I want to make it invisible to the user, so that their settings are the same on launch of the new app without knowing it's a new id/prefs file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like you ought to be able to do it with a combination of [`CFPreferencesCopyKeyList()`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFPreferencesUtils/Reference/reference.html%23//apple_ref/c/func/CFPreferencesCopyKeyList) and [`CFPreferencesCopyMultiple()`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFPreferencesUtils/Reference/reference.html%23//apple_ref/c/func/CFPreferencesCopyMultiple).